# Postgres simple tsquery fails, but should work

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I've got a simple DB setup with some columns holding TSVECTOR's using the 'simple' config.

What should be equivalent queries though, confusingly have different results

For example

```
SELECT * FROM documents
WHERE description_tokens @@ plainto_tsquery('simple', 'some text');
```

returns nothing although description_tokens contains 'some & text' and was generated with to_tsvector('simple', 'description text')

```
SELECT * FROM documents
WHERE to_tsvector('simple', description) @@ plainto_tsquery('simple', 'some text');
```

this query, which should be the same, succeeds and returns the expected results.

I've checked the column and the stored TSVECTOR contains all the same data. Am I missing something?

More searching reveals that common problems are null fields(not present here), and mixed languages/types (also not present here)

Comment: My guess would be that the type of your description_tokens column is not tsvector. If that is not the problem then provide all the SQL statements needed for reproducing this problem.

Comment: @Eelke total facepalm, I accidentally made it TEXT. Can't believe I didn't notice that sooner.